# Android - Including more than one Advertising provider in the same application. Possible?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie to android. Is it possible to include more than one Advertisement provider in an Android application? (Such as AdMob and GrayStripe)...

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own, but take a look at [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/) the code is opensource as well. This seems to be the best solution for this type of thing

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it. But I have never seen this mode in an application, so...